# Why is my badge oval?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a badge that sits on top of my cart icon and includes the number of items in the cart.

For some reason the badge is oval instead of a circle. What am I doing wrong?

```
const cartStyle = {
  width: "48px",
  height: "48px",
  verticalAlign: "middle",
  float: "right",
  marginBottom: "0",
  backgroundImage: `url(${ShoppingCart})`
};

const badgeStyle = {
   content: "0",
   background: "white",
   display: "inline",
   position: "relative",
   borderRadius: "50%",
   width: "36px",
   height: "36px",
   padding: "8px",
   left: "15px",
   border: "2px solid #666",
   color: "#666",
   textAlign: "center"
}

class Cart extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="cart" style={cartStyle}>
                <div style={badgeStyle} > { this.props.cartProducts.length } </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/stoerebink/pen/QvjYpo

Comment: You're giving `display: inline` to the `div` which doesn't affect the height and width.

Comment: use `display: inline-block; ` it will work. check the working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmevXK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use inline-block display to be able to size your element. and eventually line-height to center the text:

```css
 .bla {
  background: white; 
                   display: inline-block;
  position: relative; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  width: 36px; 
  height: 36px; 
                   line-height:36px;
  padding: 8px; 
  left: 15px; 
  border: 2px solid black; 
  color: black; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bla">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline` renders the element as inline, so the width is dependant on the content. Change to `inline-block` if you want to specify the width.

Answer (score 0):

Your display is set to inline, which means the div doesn't have the properties it needs to be able to affect the width and the height.  Set display to inline-block, which will make a circle.  If you want to vertically centre your text, set the line-height to be the same as the height, so in your case, 36px.

Answer (score -1):

It's because of its content. Due to the font-size, the badge is rendered oval. Set the font-size to 0em and it will be a nice circle.